# 'Symbol' is undefined in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, webpack, babeljs

I am using webpack + babel to enable polyfills. It works in Edge, but in IE 11 it throws `'Symbol' is undefined`.

The error is referencing this line, more specifically character 29 in this row which is the first underline of `__webpack_exports__`.

```
/* harmony default export */__webpack_exports__["default"]={name:'BCheckbox',props:{value:[String,Number,Boolean,Function,Object,Array,Symbol],nativeValue:[String,Number,Boolean,Function,Object,Array,Symbol],indeterminate:Boolean,type:String,disabled:Boolean,required:Boolean,name:String,size:String,trueValue:{type:[String,Number,Boolean,Function,Object,Array,Symbol],default:true},falseValue:{type:[String,Number,Boolean,Function,Object,Array,Symbol],default:false}},data:function data(){return{newValue:this.value};},computed:{computedValue:{get:function get(){return this.newValue;},set:function set(value){this.newValue=value;this.$emit('input',value);}}},watch:{/**
```

Why am I getting this error?

**Edit:**

I am using Laravel Mix which has [this default babel configuration](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/blob/master/src/BabelConfig.js) and here is my `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env", 
      {
        "targets": {
          "browsers": ["IE 11, last 2 versions"]
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Probably because you use a for of loop. If you do that you need to polyfill symbol for IE11.

Comment: `Symbol` is a new object type in JavaScript,  and IE11 does not support it.

Comment: https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env/issues/203

Comment: Your question has omitted the webpack and babel configs. We can't see why your attempt to enable polyfills has failed.

Comment: Sorry for omitting the config. I have updated my original question with my .babelrc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was solved by changing `import Buefy from 'buefy/src/main';` to `import Buefy from 'buefy';` Since Laravel Mix excludes *node_modules* by default.

Comment: That's what you should be doing anyway, or you'll get non-transpiled source, instead of the build.

Comment: What do you mean by *in-transpiled* source?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with another library. The difference being that the build isn't transpiled to IE 11. Should I open another issue for that one? Even though I am including the file like this: `test: /node_modules\/(vue2-google-maps)\/.+\.js$/,` – it doesn't transpile the `Object.entries`.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. I suggest you to try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. You can create a new thread for your new question to avoid any possible confusion in current thread. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Symbols are a new javascript concept that aren't supported in IE11

http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-Symbol

You'll need to change your `target` in your compiler configuration so it transpiles this to something IE11 can interpret.

Comment: I have updated my question with my `.babelrc` and as you can see, I have IE 11 in my targets.

Comment: What version of IE 11 are you using?

Comment: I am using version *11.253.17763.0* through crossbrowsertesting.com

Comment: try `"targets": { "ie": "11" }`